"SSO Authentication Errors in Microsoft Teams Extension with Teams JS SDK
Problem:
I'm developing a Microsoft Teams extension using React.js and C#. The extension uses SSO for authentication, and I consistently encounter errors during the SSO token retrieval process when testing in an incognito window. The issue does not occur when accessing the application via admin.teams.microsoft.com.
Steps to Reproduce:
1 Open Google Chrome incognito window and navigate to https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/.
2 Log into the Microsoft Teams developer platform UI.
3 Import the extension using the provided zipped file.
4 Try launching the application and observe the SSO-related errors in the developer console.
Error Messages:

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com 400 bad request

POST https://cc-frontline-backend.azurewebsites.net 401 unauthorized

Error in getAccessToken: "Exchange SSO ID Token failed with HTTP status 401"

Error in useEffect: "Failed to retrieve access token: invalid_token"


Code Snippet;
function initializeTeamsSdk(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
            console.log("Teams SDK initialized successfully.");
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

async function AuthenticateWithSSO(): Promise<IAccessTokenRequestBody> {
    await initializeTeamsSdk(); 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
            successCallback: (token: string) => {
                try{
                    const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
                    const requestBody = {
                        tenantId: decoded.tid,
                        ssoToken: token,
                        clientId: decoded.aud,
                    };

                    SetClientId(requestBody.clientId);
                    SetSsoToken(requestBody.ssoToken);
                    SetTenantId(requestBody.tenantId);

                    microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
                    resolve(requestBody);
                }catch(error){
                    reject("Token decoding failed");
                }
            },
            failureCallback: (error: string) => {
                microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
                    reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed,
                    message: error,
                });
                    reject(error);
            },
            resources: [process.env.SSO_TAB_APP_URI as string],
        });
    });
}


Technical Details:

"@microsoft/teams-js": "^1.11.0"
"@microsoft/teamsfx": "^0.5.0"

Attempted Solutions:

Verified and updated environment variables.
Checked for correct endpoint configurations.
Providing retry mechanism due to any possible network error.

Question:
Has anyone encountered similar SSO authentication issues with Microsoft Teams extensions? Any insights into whether these issues could be related to configuration, the Teams platform update, or SDK versions? How can I resolve these authentication errors?
Error Image as microsoft teams response

What's the error message you got from developer console you mentioned in step 4? I am also confusing whether you can successfully launch the app from admin.teams.microsoft.com by saying "these SSO errors do not occur". Please share more about the errors and how you get the errors.

Hi Song, as you requested i added the errors that i have encountered via the console and provided the clarity to the question and followed the rules of stackoverflow for organizing it.

Hi Erol, would you please include the error messages? You can also verify the following points first: 1. Your Microsoft Entra ID app is correctly configured with "Application ID URI
" and Teams app id is added to "Authorized client applications".  2. Microsoft Entra ID app id and application id uri is added in "WebApplicationInfo" in Teams app manifest.

Hi Bowen, I finally finished the upgrading the library (teams-js and teamsfx) to the newer version which is quite good enough and as a result the problem has been solved! Thanks for your guidance! I just wanted to give feedback for the future reference for the other developers.

You need to call app.notifySuccess();
Doc: Link
Example in use: Link
